# Value length/size limit of Fat-Free Framework global variables

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I am currently using Fat-Free Framework with an app that has a fairly long `APP_TOKEN` (~220 alphanumeric characters)

Whenever I declare the `APP_TOKEN` in config.ini - where all my globals are declared, my application for some unknown reason becomes unreachable. This has forced me to place `$f3->set('APP_TOKEN', 'XXXX...')` somewhere in my code. This works just fine, but it bugs me that one global variable was declared separately from the rest.

I tried to declare some random variable in my config.ini and assigned it to a long value (~220 alphanumeric characters) and my app became unreachable again. Is there a character limit for global variable in F3's configuration file?

Comment: Which version of F3 are you using? Even a ~500 char long string works for me with the latest version from bcosca/fatfree-core. Check your server's error log. If there's some error, it should be in there.

Comment: I'm using version 3.5.1

Comment: Even the 3.5.1 release works for me. It must be your app. Please check your error logs.

Comment: I checked my logs and there was nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: The regular expression used to parse config files is here: https://regex101.com/r/cI0wI4/1 . I have checked the example of alphanumeric string with 220 chars and it works just fine. Have you checked if a simpler value works fine?

Comment: what kind of server do you use (CentOS?) and what's the PCRE version? It must be at least 8.02. You can find it in the phpinfo()